# How to display form labels with more than one element per line? jsfiddle

Tags: css, forms, alignment, jsfiddle

I am trying to display my form labels above the form element, so I am using display:block in my CSS. However, I am not able to show more than 1 form element per line this way.

How can I update my CSS properly to show my labels above the form element, but be able to show more than one element per line? See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mhu76/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put divs around each group of span and input, and make those divs `display:inline-block;`.
I tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mhu76/4/